# Lookup using a programmatically created index string in python/QGIS?

Tags: python, indexing, lookup, qgis, pyqgis

I'm trying to add data to a shapefile based on a lookup table. So both the shapefile and the lookup table have values for landuse, rain and soil properties, and the lookup table also has values for other variables that I want to add to my shapefile based on the landuse/rain/soil values. This is something I'd be pretty confident doing in R, but it needs to be in python as that's the language used in QGIS, and I'm very new to python.

At the moment, I've simplified the problem by just working with pandas dataframes in python:

```
import pandas as pd

#1. sample data
landuses = ['Pasture', 'Pasture', 'Stonefruit', 'Vineyard']
soils = [90, 120, 150, 90]
rainfalls = [350, 450, 550, 650]

sample_dict = {'landuse' : landuses,
            'soil' : soils,
           'rain' : rainfalls}

sample_df = pd.DataFrame(sample_dict)
print(sample_df)

# 2. lookup table data
v1 = [1,2,3,4]
v2 = [5,6,7,8]
v3 = [9,10,11,12]

lookup_dict = {'landuse' : landuses,
            'soil' : soils,
           'rain' : rainfalls,
           'v1' : v1,
           'v2' : v2,
           'v3' : v3}
lookup_df = pd.DataFrame(lookup_dict)
print(lookup_df)
```

Obviously both tables will have a lot more data but hopefully you get the idea. So I want the values of `v1`, `v2` and `v3` into `sample_df` based on matching all of `landuse`, `soil` and `rain`. I've tried various solutions involving `np.logical_and()` and a few other similar things and have been able to get this to work for simplified versions but not to add the value for the table. I won't bore you any more with the details of my failed attempts so far, but I think the best solution (for my level of python programming at least) is going to be to create an index string combining the `landuse`, `rain` and `soil` values for each row and match between tables based on that. So for example, the string for the first row of `sample_df` would be `'Pasture 90 350'`, which I can add to both tables and then use as an index.

However, when I try to create the index string using:

```
sample_df['index'] = sample_df['landuse'] + " " + str(sample_df['rain']) + " " + str(sample_df['soil'])
```

It incorporates all values for `soil` and `rain` into the string, which is not what I want.

And also, when I did a test run of the next step using a simple numerical index key:

```
sample_df['index1'] = [1,2,3,4]
lookup_df['index1'] = [1,2,3,4]

sample_df['v1'] = lookup_df[lookup_df['index1'] == sample_df['index1']]
print(sample_df)
```

The `lookup_df[lookup_df['index1'] == sample_df['index1']]` part works on its own, but the assignment doesn't.

Can anyone help me? I'm guessing the solution involves using `.assign` (which I understand is the python equivalent to `mutate()` in R) but I haven't been able to figure it out. Thanks in advance for any assistance!

Comment: I've solved the first half of my problem with a `for` loop:


    `for lab, row in sample_df.iterrows() :`
        `sample_df.loc[lab, 'index'] = " ".join([sample_df.loc[lab, 'landuse'],`
       `str(sample_df.loc[lab, 'rain']),`
       `str(sample_df.loc[lab, 'soil'])])`

(Sorry, not sure how to get a proper code block in comments)

Comment: And also realised that there's an easily fixed (with hindsight) error in my last code block (was missing `['v1']` at end): `sample_df['v1'] = lookup_df[lookup_df['index'] == sample_df['index']]['v1']`

Will check this all works on my actual data before I solve my own problem, but looking good.